# For Riemann's zeta function if one proves a relation in the domain $\text{Re}(s)>1$ will this be enough to prove it is satisfied in all the z domain

Tags: riemann-zeta

Ror Riemann's zeta function if one proves a relation in the domain $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$ will this be sufficient proof that it is satisfied in all the z domain

for example if one proves $\zeta(s)=\overline{\zeta\left(\overline s\right)}$ from the original function defined in $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$ does it require another proof for $\operatorname{Re}(s)<1$ or can we say that it is satisfied for all z domain and why?

Comment: It's not too easy for me to guess what you really mean, but for example $\;\zeta(s)\neq0\;$ for $\;s\in\Bbb C,\,\text{Re}\,s>1\;$ , yet this is false in the whole domain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general question is too broad, but it is easy to answer in the case of the specific example that you mentioned. Since $\zeta(s)=\overline{\zeta\left(\overline s\right)}$ is an equality between analytic functions, then, by the identity theorem and because the domain of the $\zeta$ function is connected, if this identity holds when $\operatorname{Re}s>1$, it holds everywhere.

Comment: does this mean that for example if we solve ζ(s)=ζ(s¯) using the form of zeta function defined for re(s)>1 we will have solved it in the entire z domain?
if so how come this solution does not include the non trivial zeros ?

Comment: @MinaMaged Actually, what I did proves that $\zeta(s)=0\iff\zeta\left(\overline s\right)=0$.Since the trivial zeros are real, this provides no information about them. But it it tells us that we only need to look for non-trivial zeros with non-negative imaginary part.